# SSL protocol error

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, ssl, connection

I have Lubuntu 14.04 32 bit.
When I try to access any google site using chrome I get SSL protocol error. 
I can access yahoo or slack, but cant access google.com or gmail or youtube.
Firefox works correctly.

date and time are correct.
I tried to disable QUIC.
I tried to use wifi or ethernet.
I tried to reinstall chrome and lubuntu too.
I cant access 'change proxy settings' I get:

```
When running Google Chrome under a supported desktop environment, the system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.

But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man x-www-browser for more information on flags and environment variables.
```

any help please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs at http://askubuntu.com

Comment: I didn't know where to ask. Have no problem to ask it at askubuntu.
but I think it's chrome + ssl problem not ubuntu only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem was an old version (version 45) of google chrome for 32 bit linux system. After installing latest version (version 48) of google chrome for 32 bit linux system, there is no more ssl error.
You can download chrome version 48 from here: [google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb](http://bbgentoo.ilb.ru/distfiles/)